# CSS stick divs up against eachother when they are floating left in a container

Tags: css

how do i get the image here to stick up against the top image, rather then break in to a new line if one of the images does not fit.

```
http://www.hotchinesebabes.com/
```

The site IS safe for work, there are no females, or naked females on the site.

Here is an example of what i want to do:

[image]

Comment: Either way, safe or not, post your code here.

Comment: a good JSFiddle would be a lot more titillating for people who are interested in helping :)

Comment: Thanks il get working on one :)

Comment: Why would females be naked on a site called "[Hot chi](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hotchi) NES é Babes" ?

Comment: @JohnDOe: Check out my answer below

Comment: you can build a multi-column layout, and place those images without floating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use calculation algorithms that alter the layout with jQuery to get the layout you desire.

For example, check out these plugins:

- [CollagePlus](http://ed-lea.github.io/jquery-collagePlus/) (good!)
- [Shuffle](http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/)
- [ShapeShift](http://mcpants.github.io/jquery.shapeshift/)
- [MegaFolio](http://codecanyon.net/item/megafolio-pro-responsive-grid-jquery-plugin/3782456?ref=pxcr&ref=pxcr&clickthrough_id=166739436&redirect_back=true)
- [Grid-A-Licious](http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/) (good!)
- [Gridster](http://gridster.net/)
- [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)
- [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
- [The Engine](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-dynamic-grid-the-engine/2557493?ref=pxcr)
- [Blocks-It](http://www.inwebson.com/jquery/blocksit-js-dynamic-grid-layout-jquery-plugin/) (good!)
- [Flex](http://jsonenglish.com/projects/flex/)

This will save you lots of time and some of the plugins even have animations!

I hope this helps you out! Good luck!

Comment: @JohnDOe: Do you like them?